# unable to excecute mysql from command line

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I've installed `xampp`. I want to use `mysql` only and i want to use it in command line not in `php myadmin`. how can i do that?

I've installed `mysql` again with `sudo apt-get install mysql....5.5` so I've installed it twice once in `xampp` and once in here.

I've tried `mysql -u root -p`  but it's not working. I'm getting error as

```
can't connect to local mysql server through socket /var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock(2).
```

Comment: you can post your errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql is the client program. You need to install mysql server which you can connect to.

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.5
```

During the installation you will be asked for the root password that will be assigned to the mysql root user.

Then you need to start the mysqld service

```
sudo service mysqld start
```

Or

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld start
```

Or

```
sudo service mysql start
```

(All three lines do the same)

Finally you can connect

```
mysql -uroot -p
```

Comment: i'm getting unreconginized service

Comment: Can you try with `service mysql restart` ?

Comment: sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld start   is saying commnd not found

Comment: i got it buddy  but am i need uninstall  xampp because it also contains mysql

Comment: @ManoharManu there should be no need to uninstall xamp, just install the same server version as xamp - in the question you installed with `...install mysql....5.5` so install `mysql-server-5.5`

Comment: @Pieter thank you. i installed  mysql-server-5.5  it's working fine.